# Clustering clusters in Python OR merge clusters to reduce number of groups (Python)

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cluster-computing

I'm dealing with a set of 173k points labelized into 160 groups. I'd like to reduce this number of groups/clusters by merging the closest (to 9 or 10 groups). I've searched for sklearn or alike libraries, but with no success.

I guess it's simply clustering by knn not points but groups of same labelized points.

As graphics are most of the time better explanations, here is a simplified version of what I'd like :
[image: merging cluster 0 and cluster 1 as they are close in distance]

Thanks for the help

Comment: What are you classifying exactly? What kind of labels are you using? Couldn't you group the classes together all related classes?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [k-Means Clustering](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html)?

There, you can define the number of clusters `n_clusters` - which could be 10 in your case.

Comment: That could be a good idea, using clusters' center, and then clustering the centers. But the shapes may be ignored, this could be an over-simplification
Moreover, I already have labels, I just want to merge some until it's reduced to 10

Answer (score 0):

You have:

- X - data
- labels - current cluster labels list

To cluster clusters just add labels as a new column:

```
from sklearn.preprocess import scale
X = pd.DateFarme(X)
weight = 1
X['current_labels'] = scale(labels) * weight
# cluster again:
```

To merge cluster 3 to 2:

```
X['current_labels'] = labels
X[X['current_labels'] == 3] = 2
```